# Load pending state in db2 table

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I am getting load ending state error when I tried to resolve by the below command the data in the table will be deleted

```
load client from 'E:\test.csv' of del terminate into table name NONRECOVERABLE;
```

Can anyone suggest me the command to resolve the load pending state without deleting the data? I need the data in the table.

Comment: What was the error that caused the load to fail?

Comment: With `LOAD TERMINATE` the table will be truncated to an empty table after the operation. [Look here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008305.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response ..you are right its working

Answer (score 0):

A `LOAD TERMINATE` will terminate the interrupted load operation, and roll back the operation to the point in time at which was started.

> If the load being terminated was a `LOAD REPLACE`, the table will be **truncated to an empty table**
>
> If the load  being terminated was a `LOAD INSERT`, the table will **retain all of its original records**

See the full details in the `LOAD` page of the Db2 manual
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008305.html